# Views Data Export print feed icon in template file

Tags: views, theming, importing-exporting

I created a template for my view (views-view-fields-xxx.tpl.php).  On my view page I use the ['Views Data Export Module'](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to export filtered views in XLS format.

I cannot figure out how to display the button on the top of the page.  I tried printing it out in my template file using :

```
<?php print $view->feed_icon ?>
```

but then it prints out the button on every field view.  Is there a way to print this field only once? Or another way to move the "feed-icon" to the top of my page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution from: https://www.drupal.org/node/2117433#comment-9422881

1. Copy the views-view.tpl.php file from views into your theme (or its
   templates directory if it has one). Note that you can rename the
   file in certain ways to make it specific to an individual view or
   display. The "Theme: Information" section of the views UI will give
   you more information. Also see the blog post for more information on
   that.
2. Clear the cache so the site starts using your new template file
   instead of the default views one. The "Theme: Information" part of
   the views UI should now indicate that your file is being used.
3. In your theme's version of the template file move the feed icon
   section wherever you want it. Potentially you would put it under the
   exposed filters or something. Currently the the feed icon part of
   the template looks like this (move this whole section):

`<?php if ($feed_icon): ?>
      <div class="feed-icon">
        <?php print $feed_icon; ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Thanks @Jhilke. I've got one question.  Why does it work in my 'views-view.tpl.php' template, but not in my 'views-view-fields--xxx.tpl.php' template?

Comment: template files are bit tricky sometimes. you just need to try with different combinations... there is a documentation about how to use it, in drupal.org I guess...

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative (if you can't override the `views-view.html.twig`) would be to use a preprocess function:

```
// mysite.module

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view().
 */
function mysite_preprocess_views_view(array &$variables) {
  // Move feed icon to the top of the result, instead of buttom.
  if (isset($variables['feed_icons'])) {
    $variables['attachment_before'] = array_merge($variables['attachment_before'], $variables['feed_icons']);
    unset($variables['feed_icons']);
  }
}
```